# resolve all promises from all on click events

Tags: javascript, onclick, promise

Say we have 4 forms and each form has 4 ratio buttons with values 1-4.

I want to attach a Promise to each form and in the Promise.all(pforms) be able to add up the selected values from the clicks.  I want all promises to return after all forms have some click event.

basic dom (times this by 4 and update name from group1 - group4)

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="group4" value="1">
    <input type="radio" name="group4" value="2">
    <input type="radio" name="group4" value="3">
    <input type="radio" name="group4" value="4">
</form>
```

script

```
    <script>

        var pForms = $('form').map(function () {
            var _this = this;

            var click = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                $(_this).one('click', function () {
                    resolve($(_this).find('input[type="radio"]:checked').val());
                });
            });

            return click;

        }).toArray();

        Promise.all(pForms)
            .then(function (results) {
                console.log(results);
            });

    </script>
```

Currently, it resovles all promises when only one click event happens.

edit - now it works fine

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is.

Comment: Do you expect `$(this).one` and `$(_this).find` to refer to the same element?   If yes, why are you using `this` in one case and `_this` in the other?

Comment: That is an oversight - I'll see if that code above works with the correct this, but I don't think it will. update (doh! it does work - i just have freaking "this" wrong!)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a working solution.

```
    <script>
        function getValue () {
            return $(this).find('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
        }

        var pForms = $('form').map(function () {
            var _this = this;

            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

                $(_this).one('click', function () {
                    resolve(getValue.call(_this));
                });

            });

        }).toArray();

        Promise.all(pForms)
            .then(function (results) {
                console.log(results);
            });

    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Keep it simple. This is not an html element as you used it, and don't write a variable to define this

Comment: 1.yes! 2.i dont get your point 3.*define this* isnt possible, it just can be bound. However storing this in a variable is quite common. => wheres your answer?